# ApplicationPath vs "~", which is better to find the application path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I needed to get the Base-/Application-Path of my ASP.NET-MVC-5-Application.

I found two opportunities to get it and wonder what is the better choice:

```
UrlHelper.Content("~")
```

or

```
UrlHelper.RequestContext.HttpRequest.Request.ApplicationPath
```

Comment: I would suggest there is very little in it. ApplicationPath is likely marginally faster (it's already computed further up stream) where as the helper will need to compute it (on some level). This is likely micro-optimisations at best though.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, i think this is better

```
Server.MapPath("~/YourFolder/");
```

here "~" represents your rootfolder

ie. If you want to get "pic1.gif" file from "Contents" folder

simply use

```
string _path = Server.MapPath("~/Contents/");
string _myFile = "pic1.gif";
string _fullPath = _path + _myFile;
```

Comment: the question is *wonder what is the better choice*. You haven't answered the question

Comment: This does not provide application path at all.